# Please explain the code below (This is a question about for-loop arguments in C++):

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
char title[] = "Computer";
    for(int i=0; title[i]; i++){
        cout<<title+i<<endl;
    }
```

Please tell what is "title[i]" doing in the arguments. What role does it play in the loop? I'm confused because there should be a conditional in there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C/C++ strings are implicitly terminated with a null `\0` character, which is equal to `0`, which equates to `false`. Once the loop has iterated to one past the last character where the null character is, the loop will terminate.

Comment: Yes I think that this is the case. I would however warn you @vinil from every using this type of construct. It is a very obscure way of coding. What if the string is not correctly null terminated? You just created a loop until a random zero is encountered.

Comment: @Bart -- if the string is not null terminated you're in a great deal of trouble, and rewriting that condition won't fix it. And, while this construct is uncommon, it's certainly not "very obscure". An experienced C programmer knows exactly what it does.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oke so "maybe" I was a bit harsh looking only from the C++ point of view. Adding `0 != title[i]` would clarify a lot.